# UnauthorizedAccessException when reading from Application Directory

Tags: c#, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I am trying to read translation files from the application directory, but the call to open a Stream fails:

```
fstream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
```

I don't quite understand why, as the user persmissions for the file are present.

Does anybody know a way to overcome this?

many thanks in advance,

Philip

EDIT:

I finally found the answer myself. The FileStream accepts another parameter which defnies the file access (FileAccess.Read in this case):

```
fstream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

With this modification it works just fine.

Comment: Is this a windows app or service?  Is it a network path or local?

Comment: What operating system and where is the file?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that. It is Windows 7 with activated UAC. It is a local path on C:\Program Files (x86)\AppName\german.ini